# C# WPF ListView doesnt update Items from ObservableCollection when removed

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, observablecollection

trying to have `selectable` Items removed from an `ListView` which `ItemsSource` is `binded` to an `ObservableCollection`. `Debugging` shows that the Items get properly flagged as selected and removed the List itself. But the shown `ListView` doesnt update to the changes thus the deleted Items stay `shown`.

**View**

```
<ListView BorderThickness       = "0"
                          AlternationCount      = "2"
                          BorderBrush           = "Transparent"
                          ItemsSource           = "{Binding TestEntries}"
                          Style                 = "{StaticResource ListViewStyle}"
                          ItemContainerStyle    = "{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle}"
                          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
```

**Observable Collection**

```
public ObservableCollection<Entry> TestEntries
{
    get => new ObservableCollection<Entry>(_testEntries
           .Where(x => x.Title.ToUpper().Contains(FilterText.ToUpper()))
           .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date));
    set
    {
        _testEntries = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

**Command (to delete Items)**

```
private void ButtonDeleteCommandExecute()
{
    var toDeleteEntries = TestEntries.Where(x => x.IsSelected);
    toDeleteEntries.ToList().ForEach((obj) =>
    {
        TestEntries.Remove(obj as Entry);
    });
}
```

Hope someone can point me in the right direction

Comment: You always return new `ObservableCollection` from get, so when you try to remove item, it's removed from new `ObservableCollection` that, of course, send `CollectionChanged` but your `ListView` retrives instance of `ObservableCollection` only at once when it was initialized and it doesn't know about the `CollectionChanged` of the new collection.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks for the explanation. After changing the getter it works like a charm. Thanks a lot :).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Return the same object of your `ObservableCollection` in your `getter` so it can `notify` your `Target` to update itself as @George Alexandria Suggested.

```
public ObservableCollection<Communication> TestEntries
{
   get
   {
      return _testEntries;                  
   }
   set
   {
      _testEntries = value;
      //OnPropertyChanged(); <-- of no use
    }
 }
```

Since you want to `filter` data in you `listView`:

```
TestEntries = new ObservableCollection<Communication>(_testEntries.Where(x=>x.Title.ToUpper().Contains(FilterText.ToUpper())).OrderByDescending(x=>x.Date).ToList());
```